# aurelia: variable is not getting printed in custom component

Tags: javascript, aurelia

**weather.ts** file

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Weather {
  cityName: string = 'Hilsinki';
  constructor() {
    this.cityName = 'Hilsinki';
  }
}
```

**weather.html** file

```
<template>
        City XName: ${cityName}
</template>
```

When I print the component in any file, the cityName variable is not getting printed. I am trying this for last three days 12 hours a day.

Any kind of help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**
Utilizing the component in **welcome.html**

```
<template>
    <require from = "./components/weather.html"></require>
    <weather view-model="Weather"></weather>
</template>
```

also imported the component in **welcome.ts** as

```
import { Weather } from './components/weather';
```

Comment: How did you include the component? Can we see the HTML file that creates the `<weather>` component?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne, thank you, post updated, please check

Comment: From your updated error: element with same name already exist. You get this error when you include the element again. Check around in your code to see where else you are including it, and remove it either here / there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't `require` the viewmodel, only the view.

```
<require from = "./components/weather.html"></require>
```

If you want both the view and the viewmodel, require it like this instead:

```
<require from = "./components/weather"></require>
```

Comment: Error: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: weather.

Comment: You'd need to remove the `view-model="Weather"` and the `import { Weather } from './components/weather'`, as they are no longer necessary :)